# Fetching column name of a table

Tags: php, database

I am able to fetch data from my database and display them using php.
I am wondering how can I fetch the name of the columns of the table that containt the data? or is there any other methods I can use to diplay my date with the relatives column name?

At the moment i am caching the table in this way:

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('x ', 'x ', ' x'); 
mysql_select_db('x');

$query = "SELECT * FROM trip"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "<table >"; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   
if ($row['Day'] == date("Y-m-d"))
{
echo '<tr class="today">';
}
else {echo "<tr>";                  }
echo "<td>" . $row['Day'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['Country'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['Place'] . "</td>
<td>" . $row['Flight'] . "</td>
</tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
}
echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML
mysql_close(); //Make sure to close out the database connection
?>
```

Comment: What query are you using? Do you specify column names in your select statement, or use '*'?

Comment: another way is to use what you have right now, fetch by assoc, then get those array keys, or the most straightforward way, `DESCRIBE`, then fetch.

Comment: Please refrain from using **mysql_** functions in new code. Please look into using `mysqli` or `PDO`. [The functions that you are using have been deprecated.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)

Comment: Thank you matt clark, is the connection mode that is old style and now depriciated or is my query? or both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the old mysql_ driver, you can use:

```
$columns = mysql_list_fields('dbname', 'tablename', $connection);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-fields.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use Chris' answer using the `mysql_` function, or you can run an actual query.

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM mydb.mytable;
```